# Can we open an swf file in android?

Tags: android

In my project there are some documents with .swf extension. I need to display them in my android application once I click on a button. Is it possible to open those files in android? How can I open in my android app? I kept all those swf files in assets folder.

Please help me in this regard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SWF files are Flash animations. The Flash Player is no longer available for Android.

Comment: Hi thank you for the information. Is there any other option to open those files? My files are not videos. They are text documents with .swf format.

Comment: @user1448108: "Is there any other option to open those files?" -- get the files from whoever gave them to you in some supported format.